# Module padding in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I want to put "5px padding" for my banner in a module. I have made a template with artisteer. Simply I have added a module calling "top" in my index.php file like this:

```
<div class="logo_custom">
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" />
</div>
```

It appears the banner with "padding:0 0;". How can I put a 5px padding for my banner? I have tried with div, calling a class with css file. But doesn't work. If anyone has any idea please share it with me.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.logo_custom { padding: 5px; }
```